# serializable LookAndFeel - ClassCastException

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I need to serialize copy of LookAndFeel interface to the file. As a result i've written the following code:

```
public class SerializableLookAndFeel extend LookAndFeel implement Serializable {
    public String getID() {
        return "";
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return "";
    }
    public String getName() {
        return "";
    }
    public boolean isSupportedLookAndFeel() {
        return false;
    }
    public boolean isNativeLookAndFeel() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

While runtime i get

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel cannot be cast to
>   test.SerializableLookAndFeel

I've tried to extend MetalLookAndFeel, but on the runtime i get ClassCastException.

How do i manage to serialize LookAndFeel to file anyways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I assume that's a typo and you meant `extends` not `extend`. The `LookAndFeel` class has 2 direct *known* subclasses `BasicLookAndFeel` and `MultiLookAndFeel`.

Your exception says that you are trying to cast `MetalLookAndFeel` to your `SerializableLookAndFeel`. Your `SerializableLookAndFeel` extends `LookAndFeel`, while `MetalLookAndFeel` extends `BasicLookAndFeel`. Effectively you're trying to assign the child of a sibling to your class, which won't work.

Try extending `BasicLookAndFeel` if the problem still persists try posting your test code.

Comment: What I'm trying to do, is to get my current look from my PC and make the application load this set up every time it starts. So, i've decided to save it as a binary object.But there's a problem to do what you're suggesting - you can't do something like BasicLookAndFeel lookAndFeel = UIManager.getLookAndFeel(); the IDE won't let me to.

Comment: `UIManager.getLookAndFeel()` returns LookAndFeel which is an Abstract class. So you code should work, have you tried casting? `BasicLookAndFeel lookAndFeel = (BasicLookAndFeel)UIManager.getLookAndFeel();` what IDE are you using? Can you post code that I can run? I can't be much help without seeing the code. Also, if the problem persists, take a look in the debugger and see what `getLookAndFeel()` is returning.

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
JFrame frame=new JFrame("Test");
frame.setSize(600, 400);
TextArea textArea=new TextArea(20, 10);
frame.add(textArea);
frame.setVisible(true);
BasicLookAndFeel blaf=(BasicLookAndFeel)UIManager.getLookAndFeel();
s(blaf);
}
public static void s(BasicLookAndFeel blaf) {
try{
FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("basiclook.dat");
ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
oos.writeObject(basicLookAndFeel);
oos.close();
}catch(Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}`
java.io.NotSerializableException:java.lang.Object.I use IDEA

Answer (score 1):

1) just typos :-) not `extend LookAndFeel` but `extends LookAndFeel`

2) not good idea to [Set the Look and Feel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) as parameters, ensure that your L&F change must be:

```
try {
   UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf[index].getClassName());
   SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
   //or SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(myComponent)
} catch (Exception exc) {
   exc.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: 1) no typos at the actual code - just here. The problem is still actual

Answer (score 1):

You're doing strange things. Your `SerializableLookAndFeel` is (sort of) sibling of `MetalLookAndFeel`, so the cast just can't work.

The `MetalLookAndFeel` extends `BasicLookAndFeel` which extends `LookAndFeel` and  implements `Serializable`, so there's no point in adding `Serializable` again.

What about simply trying to serialize it as is? What happens?

Do you really need to serialize the look&feel? Wouldn't simply saving its name (or whatever) do?

Comment: see you can't do something like MetalLookAndFeel lookAndFeel = UIManager.getLookAndFeel();